# Large addition using String

Tags: java, string

Given two numbers as input, return the sum of the numbers. Note that the numbers can be very large and hence are provided as Strings

Sample Input #1:

```
add("2354725234782357","9999999999999999999999999988888888888")
```

Sample Output #1:

```
10000000000000000000002354714123671245
```

Implementation:

```
public String add(String str1, String str2) {

    int max = str1.length() > str2.length() ? str1.length() : str2.length();
    int n1[] = new int[max];
    int n2[] = new int[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        n1[i] = str1.charAt(str1.length() - 1 - i);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        n2[i] = str2.charAt(str2.length() - 1 - i);
    }
    int carry = 0;
    int sum[] = new int[max + 1];
    int k = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < max; k++) {
        sum[k] = (n1[k] + n2[k] + carry) % 10;
        if ((n1[k] + n2[k] + carry) >= 10) {
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    sum[max] = carry;
    String result = "";
    return result;

}
```

I have implemented my logic but I don't know how to get the output as a string.

Comment: Have a look at `BigInteger`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Consider padding the two `String`s so that they are the same length (by adding `0`s to the start of the smallest `String`, it should make tracking the indices easier

Comment: @NicholasRobinson using biginteger will not be helpful as i am trying to correct my program with logic.

Comment: @nisha you think you implement the logic, so where is the result stored? in sum array?

Comment: @kai , thats is the area where i got stuck ,thats why i needed help.

Comment: storing digits in decimal is easy to implement and easy to learn, but it's very slow and memory consuming. Bigint engines work in base 2^32 or 10^9 in 32-bit computers and base 2^64 or 10^19 in 64-bit computers instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a logic error in your code: you are adding the `char` value of each integer instead of the integer themselves. You can get the numeric value of a char using [`Character.getNumericValue(char ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-).

Then, you can construct the resulting String by looping over the `sum` array. The loop must be done in reverse order (to get the correct order). Beware of the first value `sum[max]`, if it is 0, we must not add it to the String (otherwise, we will get a value padded with a 0):

```
public static String add(String str1, String str2) {
    int max = Math.max(str1.length(), str2.length());
    int n1[] = new int[max];
    int n2[] = new int[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        //n1[i] = str1.charAt(str1.length() - 1 - i);
        n1[i] = Character.getNumericValue(str1.charAt(str1.length() - 1 - i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        //n2[i] = str2.charAt(str2.length() - 1 - i);
        n2[i] = Character.getNumericValue(str2.charAt(str2.length() - 1 - i));
    }
    int carry = 0;
    int sum[] = new int[max + 1];
    int k = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < max; k++) {
        sum[k] = (n1[k] + n2[k] + carry) % 10;
        if ((n1[k] + n2[k] + carry) >= 10) {
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    sum[max] = carry;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (sum[max] > 0) {
        sb.append(String.valueOf(sum[max]));
    }
    for (int i = max - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       sb.append(String.valueOf(sum[i]));
    }  
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note that you can also replace

```
int max = str1.length() > str2.length() ? str1.length() : str2.length();
```

with

```
int max = Math.max(str1.length(), str2.length());
```

Comment: what about if input is `add("-9999","999")`?

Answer (score 5):

Why don't use `BigInteger` this is much easier and still native java.

```
private static String add(String s1, String s2)
{
    BigInteger n1 = new BigInteger(s1);
    BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger(s2);
    return n1.add(n2).toString();
}
```

Anyway, there is one bug in your Code. Dont cast `char` to `int` the ascii value is used, which is wrong. Parse it with `Character.getNumericValue();`

If you have done this, you can concat `sum` array to a string in reversed order.

**Solution:**

```
public static String add(String str1, String str2) {

    int max = str1.length() > str2.length() ? str1.length() : str2.length();
    int n1[] = new int[max];
    int n2[] = new int[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) 
    {
        // conver char to int
        n1[i] = Character.getNumericValue(str1.charAt(str1.length() - 1 - i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        // conver char to int
        n2[i] = Character.getNumericValue(str2.charAt(str2.length() - 1 - i));
    }
    int carry = 0;
    int sum[] = new int[max + 1];
    int k = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < max; k++) {
        sum[k] = (n1[k] + n2[k] + carry) % 10;
        if ((n1[k] + n2[k] + carry) >= 10) {
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    sum[max] = carry;
    // concat array in reverse order
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = sum.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        sb.append(sum[i]);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Input

```
add("2354725234782357","9999999999999999999999999988888888888")
```

Output

```
10000000000000000000002354714123671245
```

Comment: using bigInteger will not helpful as i am trying to implement it logically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to append all the digits from your `int[]` from `max` to `0`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=max; i>=0; i--)
{
   sb.append(String.valueOf(sum[i]));
}  
String result = sb.toString();
```

You can also improve this to skip leading zeroes if you want:

```
boolean leadingZero = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=max; i>=0; i--)
{
   if (sum[i] != 0)
   {
        leadingZero=false;
   }
   if (!leadingZero)
   {
        sb.append(String.valueOf(sum[i]));
   }
}  
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: ,how can i remove zero ?

Comment: @nisha see my answer for this (and a bug in your code).

Comment: @Tunaki yes your code working fine, i checked my code i also edit my code n1[i]-48 and n2[i]-48.

Comment: @RobAu , thanks your suggestion also works but only issue is 0 appending in begnning ,how to remove that zero?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some code:(you can avoid array creation)

```
public static String add(String str1, String str2) {
    int carry=0;
    StringBuilder sum=new StringBuilder();

    int l1=str1.length();
    int l2=str2.length();

    while(l1>0 && l2>0){
        int s=Character.getNumericValue(str1.charAt(--l1))+Character.getNumericValue(str2.charAt(--l2))+carry;
        if(s<10){
           sum.append(s);
        }else{
            sum.append(s%10);
            carry=s/10;
        }

    }
    if(l2>0){
        while(l2>0){

             int s=Character.getNumericValue(str2.charAt(--l2))+carry;
                if(s<10){
                   sum.append(s);
                }else{
                    sum.append(s%10);
                    carry=s/10;
                }

        }


    }
    if(l1>0){
        while(l2>0){
             int s=Character.getNumericValue(str1.charAt(--l1))+carry;
                if(s<10){
                   sum.append(s);
                }else{
                    sum.append(s%10);
                    carry=s/10;
                }

        }
    }

    if(carry>0){
         sum.append(carry);
    }
    return sum.reverse().toString();

}
```

Comment: thanks but your code fails, two  inputs -'1600' '213'  your output 813 ,expected output-1813.

Comment: your should check first bit for sign